# Fedora keyboard shortcuts fail

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora

I use a bunch of Fedora keyboard shortcuts, things like `ctrl+alt+t` to open a new terminal.

I have the following keyboard shortcut setup:

```
name:     syncSrc
command:  ~/Scripts/syncSource.sh
```

And i have assigned this to `ctrl+alt+]`. The script is pretty simple, it checks that a remote directory exists and then uses `rsync` to sync it with a local directory. Running the script from a shell works just fine but when i try to use this hotkey none of the local file changes are uploaded so i suspect it isn't running?

Also when i replace the command section with just the `rsync` call, then it works, so i am interested why the script doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the command to the full path:-

```
name:     syncSrc
command:  /home/<user>/Scipts/syncSource.sh
```

The tilde (`~`) is expanded to 'your home directory' within your shell (eg `bash`), which is why it works when you type it in the terminal.  There is no shell involved when you try to invoke the shortcut, which is why it fails.